# Relationship between $tr(A^*A)$ and $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ complex matrix and let $A^*$ denote the conjugate transpose of $A$. Then which of the following are true ?
>
> a) If $A$ is invertible, then $tr(A^*A) \neq0$
>
> b) If $tr(A^*A) \neq0$, then $A$ is invertble
>
> c) If $\vert tr(A^*A) \vert < n^2$, then $\vert a_{ij}\vert<1$ for some $i,j$
>
> d) If $tr(A^*A)=0$, then $A$ is the zero matrix

b) is false, since $A=\begin{bmatrix}i & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ is an example for a $2\times 2$ case.

Another thing I know is $rank(A)=rank(A^*A)$.

So how to prove/disprove others? Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part A take the contrapositive i.e to show$ P  \implies Q $ we show ~Q$\implies $~P .Let $Tr(A^*A)=0$ this means that $\sum_{i}^n \sum_{j}^n |a_{ij}|^2=0$ .This means that each $a_{ij}=0\implies  A=0$ and hence not invertible.with this you automatically prove (d) as well.hence A and D are true. To prove C again take contapositive
 Let $|a_{ij}|$ be greater than $1$ for each $i,j $ then $|a_{ij}|^2$ is geater than $1$ for each $i,j $ and since you have $n^2 $ elements hence the sum is greater than $n^2$.Hence c is also true